# No suitable constructor was found in NUnit Parameterised tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

See the below test fixture:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using NUnit.Framework;

/// <summary>
/// Tests relating to Harry Potter
/// </summary>
[TestFixture("Dumbledore")]
public class HarryPotterTests
{
    public string Name;

    public HarryPotterTests(string personName)
    {
        Name = personName;  
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Name);
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to see how parameterised test fixtures work. I haven't used them before so this is my first stab at it.

It looks OK to me. Constructor with a string, and passing in a string in the actual test fixture attribute. It compiles. Test simply writes it out to a console window.

The test however fails with this message:

```
No suitable constructor was found
```

Am I missing something blindly obvious?

No matter where I put a breakpoint, nothing is hit, so it is failing very early on.

Comment: Where are you calling this constructor?  That is a compiler error, so of course no breakpoint will be hit since your code isn't running.

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine with NUnit 2.6, running from both the NUnit GUI and Resharper 7 test runner. Could it be that you are using an old NUnit version? Parameterized test fixtures was introduced in 2.5.

Comment: +1 for the LOL at your choice of names. (and useful question for me)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This particular problem is a bug in JustCode's NUnit Test Runner. Re-running this with Resharper 7's NUnit Runner and the NUnit GUI, both pass.

Answer (score 20):

I had this problem. It was caused by the constructor throwing an error, rather than any issue with the constructor parameters. The error message was misleading in my case.

Comment: My problem was that one of my static class helper fields was failing due to a change. So, not in the constructor code. Instead the static helpers that are instantiated on the creation of the first class instance failed. Thanks for directing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 14):

I experienced this problem - running a Test class under NUnit **and** via the Resharper 8.

However, if I changed the TestFixture declaration *from* this form

```
[TestFixture("CategoryName")]
```

*to* this form:

```
[TestFixture(Category="CategoryName")]
```

then they worked... this also improved things via NUnit - but as it happens for my particular tests I have connectionString and Entity Framework issues which Resharper helps with and NUnit does not - but essentially I believe NUnit is happier with the latter syntax.

Comment: The original question was about parameterised tests. Changing the string that would be passed as a parameter to a TestFixtureAttribute of Category are two different things. Passing the string "CategoryName" would pass the string to the constructor. Category="CategoryName" will put the test fixture in the "CategoryName" category.

Answer (score 7):

Your test class is perfectly valid and returns *Passed* when running NUnit 2.6 and .NET 4, both with the NUnit GUI and the Resharper 7 test runner.

The error you are seeing occurs when the types of the arguments in the `TestFixture` constructor does not match the types of the test class constructor. For example, if I add the line:

```
[TestFixture(10)]
```

I will get the following error in the NUnit GUI:

```
ParameterizedNunit.HarryPotterTests(10).Test:
ParameterizedNunit.HarryPotterTests does not have a suitable constructor
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - after quite some investigation, it seems it's an issue with my Nunit Test Runner. I do not use Resharper, but JustCode (Telerik). Seems like their test runner has issues with parameterised tests, as when I tried this with Resharper 7, it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Check if your constructor has any logic that might be failing.  It turns out I had a call in the Constructor (bad!) that should have been in `TestFixtureSetUp`. In Resharper this is the the default error message with parameterized test fixtures if anything throws an exception in the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Fairly obvious, but can also happen if the test's constructor is not public.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it helps someone else.
In my case, I was using TestFixtureSource, and a function to build the combinations for the different TestFixtures. Turns out that the number of element in the array did not match the number of parameters for the constructor. (I forgot the -1)